# Using Numpy for a fast list check

Tags: python, c++, numpy

Lets say I have an image and I want to go through every pixel of it to check, if it fits my needs. Using 'for' takes a lot of time in Python and I do that same thing a lot faster in C++.

I've heard that Numpy is being used for it, but I'm not sure how

basically:

```
for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, height):
        if img[x][y][0] > value:
            ...do something...
```

using this simple Python format it takes about 5 seconds for one frame, while C++ does it in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have an array `array = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` which is a 2x3 matrix which could be an image. With numpy you can simply check if a value exceeds a threshold by writing `array>threshold` which will return a 2x3 matrix with true and false. You can also write `array[array>threshold] = some new value` which will set all the values that exceeds your threshold in your array to a specific value

Comment: Or even use np.where(condition), as described in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: Problem with this is that 'array[array>threshold]' sorts all pixel values and mashes them together. I need to check every pixel and their three channels to decide what to do with each pixel.